# Getting objects from active record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to fetch all the items being followed and the for each item I want to fetch all of it's articles in an array to pass it to the view partial.
But I am not receiving objects rather I am receiving Active Record relation

Here is my code

```
@row=[]
@followed_blogs = Follow.where("followable_type == ?","Blog").where(follower_id: current_user.id)
@followed_blogs.each do |blog|
  @row << Article.where("blog_id == ?",blog.followable_id)
end
@articles = @row.sort! {|a,b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at}
```

Comment: Please [read this](http://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/) carefully. The code above smells, it mustn’t be done that way. If you have, say, 1000 blogs, this code will execute 1001 select query against the database.

Answer (score 2):

```
@followed_blogs = Follow.
  where(followable_type: "Blog").
  where(follower_id: current_user.id).
  includes(:articles)
@row = @followed_blogs.map(&:articles)
@articles = @row.sort! {|a,b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at}
```

This might work better, assuming you've got the relations set correctly between `Follow` and `Article`.

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follow, as: blog
end
```

I think that's right, you'll have to tweak it. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

With the polymorphic association set up properly, the first line becomes:

```
  @followed_blogs = Blog.
    where(follower_id: current_user.id).
    includes(:articles)
```

And if User has the correct association (`has_many :blogs` or something), it can even become

```
@articles = current_user.blogs.includes(:articles).
  map(&:articles).
  sort! {|a,b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at}
```

Comment: the `Follow` model is generated by the socialization gem that I am using and  have predefined methods for associations like `acts_as_followable` in 'Blog' and acts_as_follower in `User`

Comment: @Mr94 then you are all set up.

Comment: Sorry but I am still stuck. I am new to rails and can't figure out solution of this simple problem :(

Comment: Solved it finally. Check my answer and tell me if it will effect the sites performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
@f_blogs = Follow.where('followable_type == ?',"Blog").where('follower_id == ?', current_user.id).pluck('followable_id')
@articles = Article.having(blog_id: @f_blogs).group('id')
```